# Positive semidefinite matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $e_i$ the $i$-th column of the identity matrix. Is there an easy way to prove that the matrix 
$$\left[\matrix{\mathbb{I}_n & e_1e_2^T &  \cdots & e_1e_n^T\\ e_2e_1^T & \mathbb{I}_n & \cdots & e_2e_n^T \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ e_ne_1^T & e_ne_2^T &\cdots & \mathbb{I}_n}\right]$$
is positive semidefinite?

Comment: What does $\Bbb{I}_n$ stand for? Is this for the identity matrix of order $n$? What are the dimensions of the matrix (is it $n^2\times n^2$)?

Comment: Can you give some context? Why do you want this?

Comment: @nullgeppetto Well $\mathbb{I}_n$ is the identity matrix of dimension $n\times n$.

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen I was trying to prove the positive semidefiniteness of another matrix that involved also a vector $x$  with $\|x\|=1$ and I simplified it to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix is equal to
$$
\tilde{I}+\pmatrix{e_1\\e_2\\\vdots\\e_n}\pmatrix{e_1\\e_2\\\vdots\\e_n}^T,
$$
where $\tilde{I}$ is a block diagonal matrix where the $k$th diagonal block is the $n\times n$ identity matrix with the $(k,k)$-entry set to zero (compensated in the second term with $e_ke_k^T$). This "crippled" identity is positive semidefinite and a rank-one semidefinite matrix is added to it, so the result is positive semidefinite.